# Getting all sheets from multiple workbooks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to return data from 40 different workbooks each with two sheets. For some reason when I log this return data value, I am only getting the information from one sheet. I think I need to make a 2D array but not sure. Any ideas?

```
//Function to pull all data from workbook
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID) {

//Open workbook
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
//Get all sheets in workbook and put into array
var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
//Get data in the open sheet
var data = ws.getRange("A4:C" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
return data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Get Data from all sheets into a 2D array A4:C

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByID('id');
  var data = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getRange(4, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 3, 3).getValues()).flat(1);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  return data;
}
```

[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: If I wanted to keep them into separate arrays for sorting purposes, I can just remove the flat method, correct? My master sheet is split into two sheets just like the other workbooks.

Comment: Yes removing the flat will yield a 3 d array